# Java: 2 runtime errors I can't figure out

Tags: java

I am working on a homework assignment, and I am going a little "above and beyond" what is called for by the assignment. I am getting a run-time error in my code, and can not for the life of me figure out what it is that I have done wrong.

Here is the assignment:

> Write a program that displays a simulated paycheck. The program should ask the user to enter the date, the payee’s name, and the amount of the check. It should then display a simulated check with the dollar amount spelled out.

Here is my code:

CheckWriter:

```
/* CheckWriter.java */

// Imported Dependencies
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckWriter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Try to get the name
        String name = "";
        NameValidator validateName = new NameValidator();
        while (validateName.validate(name) == false) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (validateName.validate(name) == false) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid name.");
            }
        }

        // Get the date
        String date = "";
        DateValidator validateDate = new DateValidator();
        while (!validateDate.validate(date)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            date = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (!validateDate.validate(date)) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid date.");
            }
        }

        // Try to get the amount of the check
        String checkAmount = "";
        CurrencyValidator validateCurrency = new CurrencyValidator();
        while (!validateCurrency.validate(checkAmount)) {
            
            System.out.print("Enter the Check Amount (XX.XX):  $");
            checkAmount = keyboard.nextLine();
            
            if (!validateCurrency.validate(checkAmount)) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid check amount.");
            }
        }

        String checkWords = checkToWords(checkAmount);  // ERROR! (48)

        System.out
        .println("------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "Date: "
                + date
                + "\n"
                + "Pay to the Order of: "
                + name
                + "         $"
                + checkAmount
                + "\n"
                + checkWords
                + "\n"
                + "------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    private static String checkToWords(String checkAmount) {
        
        /**
         * Here I will use the string.split() method to separate out
         * the integer and decimal portions of the checkAmount.
         */
        
        String delimiter = "\\.\\$";
        /* Remove any commas from checkAmount */
        checkAmount.replace(",", "");
        /* Split the checkAmount string into an array */
        String[] splitAmount = checkAmount.split(delimiter);
        
        /* Convert the integer portion of checkAmount to words */
        NumberToWords intToWord = new NumberToWords();
        long intPortion = Long.parseLong(splitAmount[0]);       // ERROR! (84)
        intToWord.convert(intPortion);
        String intAmount = intToWord.getString() + " dollars";
        
        /* Convert the decimal portion of checkAmount to words */
        String decAmount = "";
        long decPortion = Long.parseLong(splitAmount[1]);
        if (decPortion != 0) {
            NumberToWords decToWord = new NumberToWords();
            decToWord.convert(Long.parseLong(splitAmount[1]));
            decAmount = " and " + decToWord.getString() + " cents.";
            
        }
        
        return (intAmount + decAmount);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using external class files to handle validation of the name, date, currency, and conversion from numbers to words.  These class files all work as intended.

The error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>
> ```
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
>
> at CheckWriter.checkToWords(CheckWriter.java:82)
>
> at CheckWriter.main(CheckWriter.java:46)
> ```

I have commented the lines in my code that are causing the errors that I am experiencing.

Could someone please assist me in figuring where my code is going wrong?  I can include the other class files if you feel that it would be needed.

EDIT:  When I run the code, it asks for the name and date.  Before asking for the check amount is when it throws the error.

EDIT 2:  A huge thank you to cotton.m!  Thanks to his advice, I have changed the while statements to look like this:

```
while(!validateDate.validate(date) && date == "")
```

This has now fixed my issue.  It would appear that when validating data with a regex expression, an empty string will return true.

Comment: Can you use the debugger and let us know what the value of splitAmount[0] is on the line of the error?

Comment: You're calling Long.parseLong on an empty string.  You can't do that.  Test for an empty string first.

Comment: The exception that you've pasted here clearly tells you which line the error is on! Why don't you just print the value being fed into the "parseLong" method to see what it is (if you don't know how to use a debugger).

Comment: I'll upvote this question as it's well formatted, clear, and tagged with homework. Welcome to SO. But really, you should be careful on reading the debugger errors and exceptions. It most often pinpoints where things go bad.

Comment: I have added a comment in the Original Post as to where the error has occurred.  I have also changed those items which have been recommended thus far, and I still encountering this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String you are trying to parse in an empty length string.

My suggestion would be to

1) Check the value of checkAmount at the start of checkToWords - if it is blank there's your problem

2) Don't do that split. Just replace the $ like you did the , (I think this is your real problem)

Also you are going to have another issue in that 10000.00 is not a long. I see you are splitting out the . but is that really what you want?

Comment: The problem is that the program never even gets to the section that is supposed to ask for the check amount.  Each subscript of splitAmount is sent separately to the NumberToWords class, so there should not be any issues there.

Comment: @shattered.likeness ah-HA! Well it is getting *past* the part where it asks for the check amount. So how is it getting past that part without asking? It must be that validateCurrency.validate returns true for an empty string. So either change that or change that loop to see what validate returns **and** that it is not an empty length string.

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to Vote you UP!  I changed values of my variables to "impossible to return true" values, and now the program is running flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

It is NumberFormatException, the value in checkAmount (method parameter) is not a valid Number.

You need to set `checkAmount=checkAmount.replace(",", "");`

Otherwise checkAmount will still have , inside and causes NumberFormatExcpetion.

Comment: Didn't catch that.  Thanks!

Still having the same issue though.  Never gets to the prompt to ask for the check amount.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with your delimiter regex, currently you are using `\.\$` which will split on a literal `.` followed by a literal `$`.  I'm assuming that what you are actually intending to do is to split on *either* a `.` or a `$`, so change your delimiter to one of the following:

```
String delimiter = "\\.|\\$"
```

or

```
String delimiter = "[\\.\\$]"
```

As your code is now, `checkAmount.split(delimiter)` is not actually successfully splitting the string anywhere, so `Long.parseLong(splitAmount[0])` is equivalent to `Long.parseLong(checkAmount)`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
String delimiter = "[\\.\\$]";
```

and then you have to check that splitWord[i] is not empty.

Comment: I have now removed the delimiter for the "$", as I have it already there in the prompt.  So now, it should only be using "\\." as the delimiter.